# How does a general Renderer::drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100) handle VBO's?

Tags: opengl, vbo

Lots of game engines and GUI systems have a general Renderer class with functions like:

```
renderer.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
renderer.drawText(204, 452, "Hello, world!");
```

I understand how this could easily be done in old immediate-mode OpenGL 2.1, but now that VBO's are the norm, could someone explain how these renderers work internally? They surely aren't creating and deleting a VBO quad everytime `drawRect()` is called, right?

Keeping one VBO and updating the vertex data is out of the question, as it would be cool to set a different shader, texture or colour in between the `drawRect()` calls.

Is instancing a (0, 0, 1, 1) rect and then scaling up the way to go?

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't see why keeping one VBO and updating the vertex data would be out of the question for you? Updating a VBO is really not that expensive. It's probably even faster than old-style `glVertex` calls...

Comment: Using one single vbo you wouldn't be able to use a different shader per quad, right? Or is that incredibly uncommon in day-to-day applications?

Comment: Besides, once you use a batch (and the painters algo; no z-ordering), *everything* has to use that batch. Or your render order screws up.

Comment: VBOs are not related to how you shade the geometry. You set the shading properties **before a draw call**, by setting shader uniforms. Unless of course you are thinking about per-vertex attributes, but usually the only per-vertex attribute you specify, which influences shading, is the vertex color. That can be replaced by a uniform variable.

Comment: But yes, indeed if you batch objects by material then, when drawing 2D without depth, Z order is compromised. You would have to then sort the objects yourself before drawing/setting up the VBO.

Answer (score 4):

There are many cleaver ways of drawing 2D geometry with modern shader-centric OpenGL. The method that I usually choose and find the most straightforward is with simple *batching*.

- On startup, create a system-side buffer of 2D vertexes (the batch). This buffer can have a fixed size or can be resizable (like a `std::vector` in C++). Also create a VBO with the same size. Indexed or not, its your choice.
- In a game frame, every `drawRect()` or `drawText()` actually writes the vertexes and material properties to this system-side memory buffer.
- At the end of every frame, map the VBO and upload the batched vertexes to it, or update it using `glBuffer[Sub]Data`.
- Render all your UI/2D stuff with a single draw call and clear the system-side vertex batch for the next frame.

This setup has two main advantages:

1. Reduced number of draw calls, you can draw everything that shares the same material properties with one call.
2. Single update of the GL buffer: You centralize your update to a single place. This will promote CPU cache efficiency and will also require very few GL API calls. There are several ways to optimize this step even further with [newer OpenGL versions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

Comment: Hmm...how would you handle multiple shaders? I reckon you'd keep one array/vector per shader?

Comment: @Frishert, just change the shader before a draw call. Each geometry batch usually groups objects that share the same shader/material. You can either use one VBO per batch or even a single VBO for all batches with a bit of extra work...

Answer (score 2):

Create a program that takes the relevant parameters as uniforms and pass those.

Then the size and position of a rect can be passed as a single vec4 uniform and you only need to pass a single VBO that is `0,0; 0,1; 1,1; 1,0` (or `0,0; 0,1; 1,1; 0,0; 1,1; 1,0` for non indexed draws)

```
in vec2 input;
varrying texCoords;
uniform vec4 posSize;//xy is the position zw is the size

main(){

    gl_Position = vec4(input*posSize.zw + posSize.xy, 0, 1);
    texCoords = input;
}
```

Then most of the magic will happen in the fragment shader where you will be sampling textures and such based on `texCoords` and your uniforms.

Comment: I like this! Basically using one quad vbo as a stamp. I guess the disadvantage would be that you wouldn't be able to use a custom vertex shader, but for some applications that would be fine.

Comment: @Frishert what would you want to do in the vertex shader that you couldn't in the fragment shader?

Comment: Hmmm...displacing vertices in a wavey pattern? I'm asking the question *because* I'm still learning about this. Can't imagine there aren't any real-life uses for a vertex shader, but definitely correct me if I'm wrong.